# Pointer Size using eeprom.h with ATmega328p in AVR-GCC

Tags: avr, atmega, programming, eeprom, avr-gcc

I am working on a project that randomly reads and writes large blocks of data from EEPROM, based on user input. I have used the EEPROM before, but I never really thought about this. In the operations described in the standard eeprom.h file ([documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html)), you always have to add a typecast to a known address location. For example:

```
DATA_BYTE = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)LOCATION);
```

This makes sense, but what i don't understand is its use for larger data, such as the following:

```
DATA_DWORD = eeprom_read_dword((uint32_t*)LOCATION);
```

Is the typecast (unit32_t) describing the pointer size, or the size of data being pointed to? I know the ATmega328p has 1kBytes of EEPROM, meaning it would take a 16 bit pointer to hold the address to a single data byte. So I'm guessing this means the typecast has nothing to do with the pointer size, but the size of the data being written/read... I know it works, I would just like to understand it better.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If even remotely possible, leave the pointers to where they belong, a task of the compiler. Check up on `avr` and `EEMEM`. You get statements like `uint8_t EEMEM eepromstring[5]={"Test\0"};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AVR, Pointers to regular memory (SRAM) are 16-bit. But EEPROM is not regular memory. The [eeprom.h in AVR Libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html) takes pointers to different data types, depending on what you actually write to EEPROM: when you read/write a byte, it takes a byte pointer, when you read/write a word it takes a word pointer, etc.  Hence the difference in the different functions you quote.  And you are right: the pointers themselves are the same size, just the size of what they "point to" is different.  You can verify this for yourself by checking what `sizeof(foo)` returns when `foo` is `uint8_t*` versus `uint32_t*`.

But, in fact, the arguments you pass to AVR Libc eeprom functions are not really pointers in the regular sense of the word: you cannot access the data they "point to" except via the EEPROM functions. It might have been clearer if the AVR Libc EEPROM functions took a `uint16_t` type called `eeprom_index` instead of a pointer type, IMHO.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. I really only figured out pointers a couple of months ago, so that's probably where my confusion comes from. I was also thinking about your second statement - them not really being true pointers since its a different kind of memory being accessed,  but I hadn't figured out how to ask about that yet. You answered it before I had a chance.